# c++ problem Given an array of strings, output the total

Tags: c++

Given an array of strings, output the total number (n) of characters in the list. Example: a = ["Dance", "with", "me"] => n = 10; for a = [] (empty array, with no elements), n = 0.

i have the following code, also available here: http://cpp.sh/8mtq4

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void){
    size_t size, i=0;
    int count=0;
    char* names[]={"Dance", "With", "Me"};

    size = sizeof(names)/sizeof(char*);

    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        printf("%d - %s\n",count+1, *(names+i));
        count++;
    }

    printf("\n");
    printf("The number of strings found are %d\n",count);
    return 0;
}
```

an idea for the next step? I did not find...

Comment: I assume you mean unique characters? Does capitalization matter?

Comment: Why is Dance with me not 11?

Comment: This isn't a homework help site.

Comment: I know that I just came for a question not to do my problems ...

Comment: Your question looks like it was copy & pasted straight from a textbook. Your code looks like some kind of homework 'boilerplate' code that was given to you with the intent for you to fill out the rest of the logic. If you had gotten this far yourself, you'd have a better "idea for the next step". You didn't even ask a question.

Comment: I found this in an exercise book, I had to ask for an idea because I was stuck at this ... it's for personal purposes no  homework or other nonsense...

Comment: maybe you are not aware, but if you are asking others to do the exercise for you, then you are wasting a chance to learn something. If you bought the book, this is a real waste of money. Whether its for homework or not, you should try yourself and come back once you have a specific problem

Comment: Are you asking for C++ or for C, because your code looks like C.

Comment: You do not have array of strings. You have array of pointers to string literals. That 2 different things.

Answer (score 1):

Add variable:

```
int totalch = 0;
```

and in the forloop,

```
totalch += strlen(names[i]);
```

and then at end print the totalch

```
printf("n=%d\n", totalch);
```